# Azure Data Factory LOOKUP possibilities

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to add a lookup activity that will look up a series of values(companyIds) and insert the values into here

["/apiCore/api/countries","/apiCore/api/Metrics/**MyLookup**"]

At present my configuration looks like the following:

[image]

I was wondering if it was possible to add Lookup activity to insert the values as follows:

[image]

And then enter a parameter like @activity('MyLookup').output.value to:

["/apiCore/api/countries","/apiCore/api/Metrics/**MyLookup**"] so it change to:

["/apiCore/api/countries","/apiCore/api/Metrics/** @activity('MyLookup').output.value**"]

Can someone let me know if the above would work? If not, do you have any suggestions?

I got the answer to my suggestion with the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.\nRequest URL: https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com/apiCore/api/Metrics/@activity('MyLookup').output.value.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=System,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "dynamoCompanies",
    "details": []
}
```

You will notice the error is with:

@activity('MyLookup').output.value

here:

```
https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com/apiCore/api/Metrics/@activity('MyLookup').output.value.,
```

Any suggestions will be very much welcomed

Updated question
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Using string interpolation, you can build the URL by adding the output of look up activity. Instead of using the URL as `https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com/apiCore/api/Metrics/@activity('MyLookup').output.value`, you can try the following:
- I have taken a sample lookup which gives the following output:

[image]

- Now, I have used a variable to build the URL value. I have taken the value `/apiCore/api/Metrics/` in a parameter called `relativeURL`.

```
https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com@{pipeline().parameters.relativeUrl}@{activity('Lookup1').output.value}
```

- This generates the required URL. When I call it in web activity, you can see the URL that is being passed in debug input (I don't have access to the activity fails).

[image]

Comment: Hi Saideep, thanks again for reaching out. This looks like the type of thing I need. I'm going to try and implement it, but I must say it seems complicated.

Comment: Hi Saideep, can you show me your variable configuration... I'm very confused

Comment: Is this the configuration that you need? https://i.imgur.com/doCuTcb.png

Comment: I think that is what I need. This will be very interesting if this works.

Comment: ok, it didn't fail, however the data wasn't extracted from ttps://pm2.preqinsolutions.com. I  think its because I need to somehow add the variable to the parameters ... At the moment the parameter called relativeURLs contain the following default values
```["/apiCore/api/Companies","/apiCore/api/Metrics/dimensions"]```. I have updated the question to show the configuration. I think I somehow need to add the variable to the parameter, correct?
I think I need to some

Comment: Can you clarify this: You need to take only the second url `/apiCore/api/Metrics/dimensions/` and make it as `/apiCore/api/Metrics/<lookup_output_array>`? Or is it something else?

Comment: Saideep, that is correct. At the moment I have ```["/apiCore/api/Companies","/apiCore/api/Metrics/dimensions"]``` and I want to add the variable such that after the adding the variable we have ```["/apiCore/api/Companies","/apiCore/api/Metrics/dimensions", "<lookup_output_array>"]```

Comment: Just so you know, I have called my variable **val** like you did. So, I'm wondering what I need instead of ```["/apiCore/api/Companies","/apiCore/api/Metrics/dimensions", "<lookup_output_array>"]``` I should have ```["/apiCore/api/Companies","/apiCore/api/Metrics/dimensions", "val"]```  ??

Comment: So you want to append the lookup activtiy output to relativeURL parameter array? is it? or the complete url (present in val variable) to relativeURL array?

Comment: I want to append the lookup activtiy output to relativeURL parameter array.. which is what ``https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com@{pipeline().parameters.relativeURLs}@{activity('MyLookup').output.value}``` does, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249476/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-patterson).